Is there a way to seed a table in Laravel for each record seeded in another table and using columns of each record? (Dependent seeding)
This is more like model event listener creating some number of other records connected to that particular record created and using a foreign key. However I want this to occur during seeding. Let's say I have a Flight model/table, I want each time I create a record either through manually or seeding, it automatically creates the seats (On the Seat model or table) which users can book.  Also the number of seats created for that flight depends on a column on the flight called "available_seats". I have already implemented this using model event listeners but it doesn't seem to work when I seed my flights.  Now because seats are usually large in number (average of 200), I may need ways to optimize the seats creation time during manually and seeding too.
This is my Flight Seeder file:
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Seat;
use App\Models\Flight;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;

class FlightSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        // Creating large record of flights using factories
        $flights = Flight::factory(20)->create();

        foreach ($flights as $flight) {
            $this->createSeats($flight);
        }
    }

    
    // Function to create flight seats
    public function createSeats(Flight $flight)
    {
        // Define the seat classes and the number of seats in each class
        $seatClasses = [
            'economy' => floor(0.70 * $flight->available_seat),
            'premium economy' => floor(0.10 * $flight->available_seat),
            'business' => floor(0.15 * $flight->available_seat),
            'first class' => floor(0.05 * $flight->available_seat),
        ];

        foreach ($seatClasses as $class => $count) {
            // Determining seat price based on price
            if ($class == 'economy') {
                $price = $flight->economy_price;
            } else if ($class == 'premium economy') {
                $price = $flight->premium_economy_price;
            } else if ($class == 'business') {
                $price = $flight->business_price;
            } else {
                $price = $flight->first_class_price;
            }

            // Loop to create class seats
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
                Seat::create([
                    'flight_id' => $flight->id,
                    'seat_number' => strtoupper(substr($class, 0, 1)) . $i, // Example: E1, E2, ..., B1, B2, ...
                    'seat_class' => $class,
                    'price' => $price,
                    'status' => 'available'
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}

It only seeds the flight table but doesn't create the seats as expected. I'm I missing something or are there ways to connect it to my model event listener?   Here is my flight factory code if required:
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Custom\Functions;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Flight>
 */
class FlightFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        // Date extension by days
        $dateAddition = rand(0, 7);

        // Base flight price
        $base_price = fake()->randomFloat(2, 1000, 5000);

        return [
            'flight_id' => Functions::generateFlightID(),
            'airline_id' => rand(1, 5), // Random airline ID between 1 and 10
            'origin_id' => rand(1, 10), // Random origin ID between 1 and 10
            'destination_id' => rand(1, 10), // Random destination ID between 1 and 10
            'departure_time' => Carbon::now()->addDays($dateAddition)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), // Departure at least today or in the next 7 days
            'arrival_time' => fake()->dateTimeBetween(Carbon::now()->addDays($dateAddition), Carbon::now()->addDays($dateAddition + 3)), // Arrival sometime between departure date and 3 days after
            'economy_price' => $base_price, // Price between 100.00 and 1000.00
            'premium_economy_price' => $base_price + 500, // Price dependent on the economy/base price
            'business_price' => $base_price + 1000, // Price dependent on the economy/base price
            'first_class_price' => $base_price + 3000, // Price dependent on the economy/base price
            'available_seats' => rand(150, 300)
        ];
    }
}


you definitely are not using the WithoutModelEvents trait any where, right? like in the main seeder?

Yes I'm not.. Actually I'm new to Laravel. I saw the WithoutModelEvents import but don't know how to use it or how it is connected to my problem

on your FlightFactoryon  on the configure(), you can do a return $this->afterCreating(function (Flight $flight) { and configure the createSeats() etc..

@francisco Please can you further elaborate? what namespace and file can I find this configure() function? And by configure the createSeats() method, you mean to define it or call it inside of the configure function?

You can use the factory callbacks with configure(). Each time you call the factory() the configure() will execute its code.
Here is the code of what you want to achieve:
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Custom\Functions;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Flight>
 */
class FlightFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        // Date extension by days
        $dateAddition = rand(0, 7);

        // Base flight price
        $base_price = fake()->randomFloat(2, 1000, 5000);

        return [
            'flight_id' => Functions::generateFlightID(),
            'airline_id' => rand(1, 5), // Random airline ID between 1 and 10
            'origin_id' => rand(1, 10), // Random origin ID between 1 and 10
            'destination_id' => rand(1, 10), // Random destination ID between 1 and 10
            'departure_time' => Carbon::now()->addDays($dateAddition)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), // Departure at least today or in the next 7 days
            'arrival_time' => fake()->dateTimeBetween(Carbon::now()->addDays($dateAddition), Carbon::now()->addDays($dateAddition + 3)), // Arrival sometime between departure date and 3 days after
            'economy_price' => $base_price, // Price between 100.00 and 1000.00
            'premium_economy_price' => $base_price + 500, // Price dependent on the economy/base price
            'business_price' => $base_price + 1000, // Price dependent on the economy/base price
            'first_class_price' => $base_price + 3000, // Price dependent on the economy/base price
            'available_seats' => rand(150, 300)
        ];
    }

     /**
     * Configure the model factory.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function configure()
    {
        return $this->afterCreating(function (Flight $flight) {
            $this->createSeats($flight);
        });
    }

    // Function to create flight seats
    private function createSeats(Flight $flight)
    {
        // Define the seat classes and the number of seats in each class
        $seatClasses = [
            'economy' => floor(0.70 * $flight->available_seat),
            'premium economy' => floor(0.10 * $flight->available_seat),
            'business' => floor(0.15 * $flight->available_seat),
            'first class' => floor(0.05 * $flight->available_seat),
        ];

        foreach ($seatClasses as $class => $count) {
            // Determining seat price based on price
            if ($class == 'economy') {
                $price = $flight->economy_price;
            } else if ($class == 'premium economy') {
                $price = $flight->premium_economy_price;
            } else if ($class == 'business') {
                $price = $flight->business_price;
            } else {
                $price = $flight->first_class_price;
            }

            // Loop to create class seats
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
                Seat::factory()->create([
                    'flight_id' => $flight->id,
                    'seat_number' => strtoupper(substr($class, 0, 1)) . $i, // Example: E1, E2, ..., B1, B2, ...
                    'seat_class' => $class,
                    'price' => $price,
                    'status' => 'available'
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}

on the DatabaseSeeder file you do a class FlightSeeder with:
public function run()
{
    $flights = Flight::factory(10)->create(); // seeds 10 flight with the seat from the configure().
}

You can configure the ->afterCreating() for factory()->create() and ->afterMaking() for the factory()->make();.

Just tried this but didn't work. Created no seat record

do you have the seat factory? Check the imports. how is your seeding file? .And I've changed the code use seat factory, not model.
